# Enable an disable button in a custom Ribbon Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have a button in a custom Ribbon, associated with the appointments window, which after being run is disabled, and the opening of a new window is rehabilitated.

Currently I have written the following code which disables the button.

```
    public bool active = true;

    public bool GetEnabled(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return active;
    }

    public void OnAddLinktButton(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        try
        {
            active = false;
            var inspec = this.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
            if (inspec is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                ribbon.InvalidateControl(control.Id);
                Appointment_Value gapp = new Appointment_Value(true, inspec);
                gapp.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Info("The following error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I can not do that enable opening. Every idea or correction also on the present code is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the following line of code:

```
var inspec = this.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
```

You need to use the [Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol.context.aspx) property of the IRibbonControl interface to get an object which represents the active window containing the Ribbon user interface that triggers a callback procedure - Explorer or Inspector.

To get the button enabled back you need to use the [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860256.aspx) or [InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861131.aspx) methods of the `IRibbonUI` interface.

For example, a raw sketch in VB.NET:

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 

Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
  Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 

Sub myFunction() 
  MyRibbon.Invalidate() ‘ Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in’s controls 
End Sub
```

As you see an instance of the `IRibbonUI` interface is passed to the onLoad callback declared in the Ribbon XML:

```
  <customUI … OnLoad=”MyAddinInitialize” …>
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did not understand what you propose. If you mean to use the Invalidate in Inizialize function, that in C# it should be Ribbon_load, I already tried to set action = true and call MyRibbon.Invalidate(). but don't work

Comment: Was the `GetEnabled` callback invoked? Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: if you ask me in a generic way if I have debugged, I can only answer yes, but of course it depends on what you expect I've searched with debugging. From what I know, the GetEnabled is the callback that allows me to set the value of the button's attribute getEnabled . What I wrote is the function that is called, the process that invokes it is implicit in the framework and I does not know in depth his steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix my problem changing the previous code

```
    public bool GetEnabled(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        bool active = true;
        string Appointment_body = control.Context.CurrentItem.Body;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Appointment_body) && !Appointment_body.Equals(" "))
        {
            active = false;
        }
        return active;
    }
    public void OnAddLinktButton(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        try
        {
            var inspec = this.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
            if (inspec is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                Appointment_Value gapp = new Appointment_Value(true, inspec, ribbon);
                gapp.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Info("The following error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Essentially I check if the body is not empty, in which case I disable the button, and then step to the function that creates the appointment (appointment_value) the value of the ribbon to place an ribbon.Invalidate()